# Docker desktop for windows - Getting Sqlcmd: 'DATABASE': Unknown Option

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-desktop

While running the below query on windows cmd

```
docker exec -it %containerName% /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost    -U SA -P %dbPassword%    -Q 'ALTER DATABASE MyTest SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;GO'
```

I am getting error `sqlcmd: 'DATABASE': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help.`

While when I am running `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost    -U SA -P mypass    -Q 'ALTER DATABASE MyTest SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;GO'` on Docker cli it works properly.

What could be the reason that running the same query from windows cmd throws DATABASE unknown error?

Comment: It's not SQL Server saying that the database is unknown, it's SQLCMD saying that "database" is an unknown option. Seems like `%dbPassword%` is empty so it's interpreting `-Q` as the password, then not knowing what to do with the quoted query.

Comment: Interesting...I have set windows environment variable for dbPassword but looks like it does not get transferred to sqlcmd

Comment: so I tried docker exec -it localdb /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost    -U SA -P myPass    -Q 'ALTER DATABASE MyTest SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;GO' but it gave the same error

Comment: Ok so the issue was single quote-- docker exec -it %containerName% /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost    -U SA -P %dbPassword%    -Q "ALTER DATABASE MyTest SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;"  --this works fine